# Как обновить div при переходе с мобильного на десктоп?

Tags: html, media-queries

Как обновить div при переходе с мобильной ширины экрана на десктопную. Под "обновить" я понимаю то, что происходит после нажатия на кнопку обновить страницу в браузере. Может можно это как-то сделать медиа запросами?

Comment: а если у меня компьютер размером 320 * 640? это будет 'мобильная ширина'?

Comment: Ок, переход с 1024 на 1270.

Answer (score 0):

c 1024px до 1270px экран желтый

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1270px) {
  div {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: (если что я новичок) Не очень понятно как это мне поможет.

Comment: @iAndyPC обновил

Comment: экран всегда чёрный

Comment: @MaximLensky экран желтый* с 1024 до 1270

Comment: Просто не знаю как точнее сформулировать, может нужно "восстановить до состояния только что открытого сайта"

Comment: щас да - заработало

Comment: @iAndyPC можете посмотреть на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1121977/331312 там адаптив с помощью медиазапросов. Можете мне написать в вк, если есть вопросы, у меня в профиле есть ссылка в вк